# Is private necessary for a standalone Java app?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit

I have read through a bunch of best practices online for JUnit and Java in general, and a big one that people like to point out is that fields and methods should be private unless you really need to let users access them. Class variables should be private with getters and setters, and the only methods you should expose should be ones that users will call directly.

My question: how strictly necessary are these rules when you have things like standalone apps that don't have any users? I'm currently working on something that will get run on a server maybe once a month. There are config files that the app uses that can be modified, but otherwise there is no real user interaction once it runs. I have mostly been following best practices but have run into issues with unit testing. A lot of the time it feels like I am just jumping through hoops with my unit testing getting things just right, and it would be much easier if the method or whatever was public or even protected instead.

I understand that encapsulation will make it easier to make changes behind the scenes without needing to change code all over, but without users to impact that seems a bit more flimsy. I am just making my current job harder on the off-chance it will save me time later. I've also seen all of the answers on this site saying that if you need to unit test a private method you are doing something wrong. But that is predicated on the idea that those methods should always be private, which is what I am questioning.

If I know that no one will be using the application (calling its methods from a jar or API or whatever) is there anything wrong with making everything protected? Or even public? What about keeping private fields but making every method public? Where is the balance between "correct" accessibility on pieces of code, and ease of use?

Comment: Is it necessary? No. There is nothing that will prevent you from writing bad code. Is it still a best practice? Absolutely.

Comment: Every method should use the **most** restrictive **appropriate** level of access. If every method is `private` then you have no `public` interfaces (not particularly useful), but if every method is `public` then it is part of the API (and must be maintained/supported). That's a long way of saying, it **will always** ***depend*** on context. Finally, you shouldn't make fields `public` (because, as you noted, that violates the principle of encapsulation).

Comment: It also reduces complexity of code and makes things easier to manage. Excellent post here about it: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/143736/why-do-we-need-private-variables

Comment: "Users" in this context means "users of the code". That may only be other classes you write (or might write in the future, as the application expands). The point of making state private is that it allows you to write a class which is guaranteed always to be in a consistent state (and to modify it later in ways which guarantee the same thing). If you make the state accessible now, and come back to change the class later, you have to remember all the places you might have used that state and the ways you might have used it. Your opportunities for changing the code are greatly reduced.

Comment: If you really want to test a private method, **probably** the class that own this method could be refactored and this method moved to another class, where this method can be public and tested directly. This kind of scenario that you describe could be a _bad smell_.

Comment: One other point here: I've never really understood the argument that properly encapsulating a class makes "my current job harder". Any IDE worth using will generate accessor methods for all your fields with about 4-5 mouse clicks. How are you actually making your current job harder by doing this?

Comment: An example where fields are NOT private is Dimension. Yes, there are getters and setters for width and height, but those variables are public for convenience. There is often no need for a variables to be private when there are no side effects when its value is changed. On the other hand, if there ARE side effects - or there are limits on the allowed values of the variable - the variable should definitely be private so the setter can set the new value and make other appropriate changes

Comment: @James_D Your first comment is a good point. I can see how limiting which methods other classes can use is useful. For your second point, my concern is honestly less on fields and more on methods. I don't really mind generating getters and setters for a field, although there are times when they feel extraneous still (e.g. only used to verify things in unit tests)

Comment: @D.Spetz I guess I see the issue even less with methods. Why does making methods private make anything harder? It means you have complete control (and knowledge) of where the method is called from, without any additional effort; I would regard this as making your life easier.

Comment: @FredK Making the state of `Dimension` public is widely regarded as a mistake, though. From Bloch, *Effective Java 2nd ed*, Item 14: "Several classes in the Java platform libraries violate the advice that public classes should not expose fields directly. Prominent examples include ... `Dimension`... . Rather than examples to be emulated, these classes should be regarded as cautionary tales. As described in Item 55, the decision to expose the internals of the `Dimension` class resulted in a serious performance problem that is still with us today."

Answer (score 2):

It is not "necessary", but applying standards of good design and coding principles even in the "small" projects will help you in the long run.

Yes, it takes *discipline* to write good software.  Languages are tools that help you accomplish a goal. Like any tool, they can be misused, and when misused can be dangerous.  Power tools, like a table saw, can be very dangerous if misused, so if you care about your own safety you always follow proper procedure, even if it might feel a little inconvenient (or you end up nicknamed "stubby").

I'd argue that it's on the small projects, where you want to cut corners and "just write the code", that adhering to the best practices is most important.  You are training yourself in the proper use of your tools, so when it really matters you do the right thing automatically.

Also consider that projects that start out "small" can evolve over time to become quite large as you keep adding enhancements and new functionality.  This is the nature of agile software development.  If you followed best practices from the start you'll find it much easier to adapt as the project grows.

Another factor is that using OOP principles is a way of taming complexity.  If you have a well-defined API and, for example, use only getters and setters, you can partition off the API from the implementation in your own mind.  After writing class `A`, when writing a client of `A`, say `B`, you can think only about the API. Later when you need to enhance `A` you can easily tell what parts of `A` affect the API vs what parts are purely internal.  If you didn't use encapsulation you'd have to scan your entire codebase to see if a change to `A` would break something else.

Do I apply this to EVERYTHING I write? No, of course not.  I don't do this with short single-use scripts in dynamic languages (Perl, AWK, etc) but when writing Java I make it a point to always write "good" code, if only to keep my skills sharp.

Answer (score 1):

There is generally no necessity to follow any rules as long as your code compiles and runs correctly.

However code style "best practices" have proven to enhance code quality, especially *over time* when a project develops/matures. Making fields private makes your code more resilient to later changes; if you ommit the getters/setters and access fields directly, any changes to a field impact related code much more directly.

While there is seemingly no advantange in a getter/setter *at first*, the advantage lies in the future: A getter forces any code working with the attribute through a single point of control which in case of any changes related to that field helps either mask the concrete representation/location of the field and/or allows for polymorphism when required whithout changes/checking all the existing callers.

Finally the less surface (accessible methods/fields) a class exposes to other classes (users) the less you have to maintain. Reducing the exposed API to the absolute minimum reduces coupling between classes, which again is an advantage when something needs to be changed. Striving to hide the inner workings of every object as good as possible is not a goal by itself, its the advantages that result from it that are the goal.

Answer (score 0):

As always, good balancing is always required. But when in doubt, it is better to error/lean on the side of "source code quality" practices; instead of taking too many shortcuts; as there are many different aspects in your "simple" question one should consider:

1. It is hard to anticipate what will happen to some piece of software over time. Yes, you don't have any users today. But you know what: one major property of **great** tools is ... as soon as other people see them, they want to use them, too. And all of a sudden, you have users. And feature requests, bug reports, ... and make no mistake: first people will love you for the productivity gain from your tool; and then they will start to put pressure on you because all of a sudden your tool is essential for other people to make their goals.
2. Many things are fine to be addressed via convention. Example: sometimes, if I would only be using public methods of my "class under test", unit tests become more complicated than necessary. In such a case, I absolutely have no problem about putting a getter here or there that allows me to inspect the internal state of my "class under test"; so that my test can trigger some activity; and then call the getter. I make those methods "package protected"; and I put a `// used for unit testing` above them. I have not seen problems coming out of that informal practice. Please note: those methods should only be used in test cases. No other production class is supposed to call them.
3. Regarding the core of your question on *private* stuff: I think, one should **always** hide implementation details from the outside. Whenever you write a piece of code that is supposed to live longer than the next hour, you should do the right thing - and try to write code with very high quality. And making the internals of your objects visible on the outside
   comes only with drawbacks; there is nothing positive in doing so.
   Good OO is about using *models* that come with certain behavior.
   Internal state should stay internal; there is no benefit in
   exposing. For the record: sometimes, you have simple data
   containers. Classes that only have some fields, but no methods on
   them. In that case, yeah, make the fields public; there is (not
   much) advantage in providing getters/setters. ( See "Clean Code" by
   Robert Martin, chapter 6 on "Objects and Data structures")